# Ionic creating assets folder in my root structure for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, gulp

Experiencing a weird problem that I'm wondering if other people have encountered.

Basically I'm having an issue that when my gulp watch is ran it creates a assets folder inside  appName (path: appName/assets/js/modules.js)

It is also making a js file in the assets inside the app folder structure which you can see below.

My question is why is there an assets folder being created as a child of appName when my watch scripts run?

It seems this is default behaviour from Ionic but would like to know how to stop it from being created and just rely on the js file inside app/assets/js/.

I have the below folder structure:

```
appName 
  assets // UNWANTED
    js
  www  
    app
      shared
      states
      modules.js
      routes.js
    assets
      css
      libs
      img
      js
    index.html
  gulpfile.js
  ionic.project
```

This is my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
    sass: ['./www/assets/scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'scripts']);

// Task is to compile the Sass into one file.
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./www/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css'));
});

// Task is to watch for any changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./www/app/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

// Concatenates all of our JS into one file.
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('./www/app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('modules.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/js/'));
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function () {
    return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function (data) {
    gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
});
});

gulp.task('git-check', function (done) {
    if (!sh.which('git')) {
        console.log(
            '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
            '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
            '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
            '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
        );
        process.exit(1);
    }
    done();
});
```

and this is my ionic.project file:

```
{
  "name": "figr",
  "app_id": "",
  "gulpStartupTasks": [
  "sass",
  "scripts",
  "watch"
 ],
 "watchPatterns": [
    "www/**/*",
    "www/assets/**/*",
    "!www/lib/**/*"
 ]
}
```

*** UPDATE *** 
I've updated my question so you can more easily see the folder structure. The problem is that the gulp 'scripts' task appears to be placing modules.js in '/appname/assets/js' (marked with 'UNWANTED' in the folder structure diagram) as well as in './www/assets'.

Answer (score -1):

No idea why. If someone knows please let me know.

but restarting my computer and then running ionic serve fixed my problem. I didn't have to write any code differently just a reboot..

If anyone knows why please add an answer and I'll accept it.

Cheers